# What is the fastest way to send vector<vector<double>> from one process created in x86 platform to another process built in x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, mfc

I have two processes **p1** and **p2**.
**p1** is built in x86 and **p2** is built in x64 platform using (Visual Studio 2013/MFC/C++)

**p1** calculates result and holds it in 
`std::vector<std::vector<double>> data`.
and I want this `data` to be transfered from **p1** to **p2**'s  `std::vector<std::vector<double>> data` in a way as fast as possible.

I have used `boost::archive::text_iarchive` to write it to text file. As it is cross platform compatible, I can read it using `boost::archive::text_oarchive` in **p2**. But it takes too much time as it involves disk reading and writing. So I need better way to do this job.

Kindly suggest me some faster way for cross platform data transfer. I will be highly thankful if someone could provide me some code also.

Comment: Within a single machine I assume? Shared memory most likely. Or at least writing it in binary rather than text if ever a file is needed. Or since it’s inside vectors maybe just pushing through a pipe

Comment: You might want to look at [`cereal`](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/quickstart.html).

Comment: If your 2D array is rectangular, transform it into a 1D array, and allocate storage for it in a file mapping object (see [Creating a File Mapping Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/creating-a-file-mapping-object)). If your 2D array is jagged, you can only store individual rows in the file mapping object. Make sure you also keep the meta data describing the data (dimensions, sizes) in the file mapping object. A file mapping object can be mapped into processes of any bitness, without the need to actually copy data.

Comment: Within a beowulf cluster, I assume?  Using IPC, probably via TCP/IP sockets, and sending the data over as binary.

Comment: Behold the answer that saved the question. v v

Comment: "**p1** calculates result and holds it in `std::vector<std::vector<double>> data`". Is using `std::vector` mandatory? I mean, if you release this requirement, then you can avoid "send"ing altogether, it will take zero time.

Comment: vector is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

As others already mentioned, the fastest and straight forward way would be to use shared memory. Below is an example of how that would look like for Posix systems.

The server creates a shared memory object and serializes the vector into the memory by writing each sub vector as length plus items.

The receiver opens the shared memory object and deserializes the memory into a vector of vector object again.

Sender:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

static const std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec = {
  { 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 },
  { 2.0, 2.1 },
  { 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 },
};

int main(int argc, char *const argv[])
{
  uint64_t vecsSize = 0;
  for (const auto& v : vec) {
    vecsSize += sizeof(double) * v.size() + sizeof(uint64_t);
  }

  // create a file of size 'vecsSize'
  int fd = open("VEC", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  lseek(fd, vecsSize - 1, SEEK_SET);
  write(fd, "", 1);
  lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

  // memory map the file into the process and copy the data into it
  uint8_t* ptrFile = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(mmap(0, vecsSize, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0));
  uint8_t* ptr = ptrFile;
  for (const auto& v : vec)
  {
    reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(ptr)[0] = v.size();
    ptr += sizeof(uint64_t);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), reinterpret_cast<double*>(ptr));
    ptr += sizeof(double) * v.size();
  }

  munmap(ptrFile, vecsSize);
  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Receiver:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, std::vector<T> const& v) {
  for (auto const& i : v)
    o << i << " ";
  o << std::endl;
  return o;
}

static std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;

int main(int argc, char *const argv[])
{
  int fd = open("VEC", O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

  struct stat fileStat = { 0 };
  fstat(fd, &fileStat);

  uint64_t vecsSize = static_cast<uint64_t>(fileStat.st_size);
  uint8_t* ptrFile = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(mmap(0, vecsSize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0));

  uint8_t* ptr = ptrFile;
  while (ptr < ptrFile + vecsSize)
  {
    uint64_t vecSize = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(ptr)[0];
    ptr += sizeof(uint64_t);

    std::vector<double> v(
      reinterpret_cast<double*>(ptr),
      reinterpret_cast<double*>(ptr) + vecSize);
    ptr += sizeof(double) * vecSize;

    vec.emplace_back(v);
  }

  munmap(ptrFile, vecsSize);
  close(fd);

  std::cout << vec;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's certainly not the fastest way, as the question is asking for. The fastest way would be to construct the memory backing of the vector in shared memory. You can pass a custom allocator to any standard container to make this happen.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for sharing your valuable comments.